# Remove dir name from url with .htaccess mod rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a codeigniter project and i have the following url:

> mysite/Project/frontend/tournaments/table

and i would like to turn it into:

> mysite/Project/tournaments/table

What should i write in .htaccess??
This is what i already have:

```
RewriteEngine on

#Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This is not a place to ask people to do your work / write your code for you. Show some effort. If you have already made an attempt and failed, include your attempt in the question. If you haven't yet made an attempt, now would be the time to do so.

Comment: Thank you, @Patrick Q. Well, i've tried a bunch of options, but none seem to work. eg. I've tried 'RewriteRule ^frontend/(.*)$ /$1 [QSA]'

Comment: Have you tried configuring it in Route.php?

Comment: @Sobiaholic I have taken it into consideration but i can't figure out how i could do that. I've no notion whatsoever of RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it?

```
 RewriteRule ^mysite/Project/frontend/tournaments/table/([^/]*)$ mysite/Project/tournaments/table/$1
```

Simple Rewrite rule will solve your problem i think

Comment: Well, even before trying this i see there's a sort of a problem with it. I'm aiming for the url to work for every address that follows frontend. Eg: mysite/project/frontend/segment4/segment5/...

Answer (score 0):

So, this is how I would do it using CodeIgniter Routing feature:

Assuming Tournaments is your controller.

```
//Example: mysite/Project/tournaments/2332
// Will accepts numbers or letters
$route['Project/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Project/frontend/$1/$2';


//Example: mysite/Project/tournaments/table
// Will accepts only letters.

$route['Project/([a-z_]+)/([a-z_]+)'] = 'Project/frontend/$1/$2';
```

You can add another route rule for admin URLs like the following:

```
//Example: Project/admin/users/add
// You can use either (:any) or ([a-z_]+)
$route['Project/admin/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Project/admin/$1/$2';
```

I suggest you to read [Routing documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html), it's a bit tediuos at the begining, but it will help you a lot!

Comment: I really really appreciate your interest. You've made me realise that i haven't explained my situation well enough. The controllers in my project are divided into several folders. The users can only see the 'frontend' part. But i do not want all the routes ['mysite/Project/(:any)/(:any)'] to go to 'mysite/Project/frontend/$1/$2'. Some of them will go to other dirs, such as mysite/project/admin/segment/segment

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps!